# Can I Write-Warning in a powershell script without a newline at the end?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I want to print a Warning in PowerShell as a prompt and then read the answer on the same line. The problem is that `Write-Warning` prints a newline at the endof the message, and one alternative, `Read-Host -Prompt`, doesn't print the prompt to the warning stream (or print in yellow). I've seen `Write-Warning -WarningAction Inquire`, but I think that's a little verbose and offers options I don't want.

The best I've done is:

```
  $warningMsg= "Something is wrong. Do you want to continue anyway Y/N? [Y]:"
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow -NoNewline $warningMsg
  $cont = Read-Host
```

This works great--prints the yellow prompt and then reads the input on the same line--but I'm wondering about the warnings I've seen against using `Write-Host`, if it's more appropriate to figure out some way to print to the warning stream without a newline. Is there a way to do that? I've noticed that `Write-Host` seems to be a wrapper to write to the Info stream, but I don't see any way to write to warnings without a new line (`[Console]::Warning.WriteLine()` doesn't exist for example).

Comment: the warnings about `Write-Host` are ... often overblown. [*grin*] if you want to write to the screen AND you want color AND you are willing to give up the ability to cleanly disable that writing ... then `Write-Host` is the correct thing to use.

Comment: Write-Host "evilness" disappeared with the introduction of PS 5. I understand that before that it was problematic but nowadays, it does write in the informaiton stream (see answer for more details about that) 

@Lee_Dailey I was curious about the "give up" fact so I checked. You can still disable that writing through `-InformationAction` parameter (see the Bonus section in my answer [grin back])

Comment: @SagePourpre - ah! thanks [*grin*] ... i had forgotten about how `-InformationAction` changes `Write-Host` ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you want with `Write-Warning`.

Therefore, I will answer regarding your other concern.
`Write-Host` is perfectly fine to use in a PowerShell 5+ script.

If you look at the articles recommending against its use, you will notice that the vast majority (if not all) were written before the introduction of PowerShell 5.

Nowadays, `Write-Host` is a wrapper around `Write-Information`.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7) confirms this:

> Starting in Windows PowerShell 5.0, `Write-Host` is a wrapper for
> `Write-Information` This allows you to use `Write-Host` to emit output to
> the information stream. This enables the capture or suppression of
> data written using `Write-Host` while preserving backwards
> compatibility.
>
> The `$InformationPreference` preference variable and `-InformationAction`
> common parameter do not affect `Write-Host` messages. The exception to
> this rule is
> `-InformationAction Ignore`, which effectively suppresses
> `Write-Host` output.

Writing to the information stream using `Write-Host` and / or `Write-information` won't create problems with your output string.

```
Stream #    Description          Introduced in
1           Success Stream       PowerShell 2.0
2           Error Stream         PowerShell 2.0
3           Warning Stream       PowerShell 3.0
4           Verbose Stream       PowerShell 3.0
5           Debug Stream         PowerShell 3.0
6           Information Stream   PowerShell 5.0
*           All Streams          PowerShell 3.0
```

**Bonus**

You can also control the visibility of the information stream if you use an advanced function through the `-InformationAction` parameter, provided you also bind the given parameter value to the `Write-Host` statements in the function.

For instance, if you wanted to disable the Information stream by default  unless requested otherwise:

```
function Get-Stuff {
     [CmdletBinding()]
     param ()

     if (!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('InformationAction')) {
        $InformationPreference = 'Ignore'
     }
     Write-Host 'This is the stuff'  -InformationAction $InformationPreference -ForegroundColor Green
}

# Hidden by default
Get-Stuff
# Force it to show
Get-Stuff -InformationAction Continue
```

**Note**

While technically it is not possible to use `Write-Warning -NoNewLine`, you could look into manipulating the cursor position and resetting it to the end of the previous line, therefore doing the same.

However, I have limited experience with that and my observations regarding the subject were that you might end up having to create exceptions to comply with limitations of some console environments. In my opinion, this is a bit overkill...

**Additional references**
[About_redirections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7)

Comment: It seems if I could just redirect Info to Warning, maybe I could do it, but that doesn't see to be possible yet.